# Stop successful await task

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using `async/await` `Task` to avoid the wpf UI been blocking and to make my application more responsive. Here's how I apply the `async/await` in my application:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      .......

      try
      {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                  ......
            });
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            ......
      }    
}
```

Do I need to stop/cancel the `Task` if it returns error in the `catch` execution? If the 'Task' is run successfully without error or any exception is caught, do I still need to stop/cancel the `Task` at somewhere else in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to stop/cancel the Task if it returns error in the catch execution?

- No, you only Stop / Cancel using `CancellationTokenSource`, if absolutely required as an explicit action (part of logic), not for exception / successful run, both of them will propagate back to the caller.

In this case its in-fact acceptable to use void, being an `async button click event`, since UI knows how to handle the exception, if it propagates

However, please understand another aspect of your code, following:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                  ......
            });
```

Will start the `Async` call on a `ThreadPool thread`, now you cannot use it to update any of the UI controls, which would lead to `InvalidOperationException`, that needs to be done on the UI thread, which is the `standard synchronization context` of an `Async` call

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the `catch` block the task has already stopped executing.

Answer (score 2):

> If the 'Task' is run successfully without error or any exception is caught, do I still need to stop/cancel the Task at somewhere else in my application?

Tasks only complete once.

If it has already completed (either successfully or with an exception), then it can't be canceled.